# Issue in case statement

Tags: sql-server

I have the following `case statememt` in my project.

```
tbl_ExceptionStatus.ExceptionStatusValue IN (case when @excstat='Awaiting ERR Approval' then ('1') else @excstat END)
```

Which is working fine but I have to change it to this

```
tbl_ExceptionStatus.ExceptionStatusValue IN (case when @excstat='Awaiting ERR Approval' then ('1','2','3') else @excstat END)
```

which is giving error 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3' to data type smallint.

How am I able to change my `case statememt` to terminate the error?

Answer (score 2):

You have a statement of the form

```
A IN (CASE WHEN @x='someString' THEN ('1', '2', '3') ELSE @x END)
```

which is not valid (you can't return a list in a case statement).

You can rewrite it as follows:

```
   (@x = 'someString' AND A IN ('1', '2', '3'))
OR (@x <> 'someString' AND A = @x)
```

If `A` can never be `'someString'`, this can be simplified to

```
A = @x OR (@x = 'someString' AND A IN ('1', '2', '3'))
```

Comment: how will i use this in my where statement i dont understand

Comment: @Ashu: What exactly don't you understand? You just have to replace `A` with `tbl_ExceptionStatus.ExceptionStatusValue`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Case statement follows datatype precedence ,whatever datatype is hightest in then and else clause,it tries to convert them to that data type..See below example

```
declare @a int
set @a=1

select case when @a=1 then 'a' else 2 end
```

the above fails  with

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int

in your case

```
then ( '1,2,3' )--varchar
 else @excstat ----int
```

written form of your query doesn't throw error

```
('1','2','3')
```

but this does..

```
'1,2,3'
```

Comment: how will i use this in my where statement i dont understand